# How to reload resources (HTML/CSS/JS) on version change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, gruntjs, version

I have a Web Application using AngularJS, oclazyload, ui-router, bootstrap and so on and I'll have updates coming out in the future, and I need to make sure that the browsers won't keep showing the cached resources, even when an updated version is available.

For this I have configured my Gruntfile (using grunt-replace, grunt-prompt and grunt-bump) to append the version number to every URL in my index.html every time I create a new build.

This works fine, but since I use ui-router and oclazyload, I have lots of resources loading lazily and only on demand, so I tried to implement an Angular Http Interceptor to append the version number to every XHR URL. This however messes up template scripts (like `<script type="text/ng-template" id="menu-item.html"></script>`). I did add conditions to avoid this, but it feels very hacky and prone to error.

Is there any fool-proof solution / best-practice for this in Angular, vanilla JS, Grunt or any other way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can lazyload assets without **cache**: just set the cache parameter to *false*.

You can also set the cache property for an array or a single file.

> There are two ways to define config options for the load function. You can use a second optional parameter that will define configs for all the modules that you will load, or you can define optional parameters to each module.
>   For example, these are equivalent (except that the first two files won't be cached in the first example):

```
$ocLazyLoad.load([{
  files: ['testModule.js', 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'],
  cache: false
},{
  files: ['anotherModule.js'],
  cache: true
}]);
```

and

```
$ocLazyLoad.load(
  ['testModule.js', 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js', 'anotherModule.js'],
  {cache: false}
);
```