# AngularJS Single Page Application Architecture

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

So I have started developing a single page web application using AngularJS. To give you an idea of the size of this application, it will have around 20-30 APIs and 100's of endpoints. The biggest advantage of using this approach is that complete app gets downloaded in the beginning and calls are made to back-end later to populate data in different screens (similar to a mobile app). While the overall experience is very good, I am starting to wonder if this is the right approach for a website of this scale. My main concerns are:

- Will this approach increase initial load time drastically as all templates, javascript and css is downloaded in the beginning?
- What happens if I update a template or javascript on server and users keep using the downloaded app which will not be compatible with the back-end? Should I add a client version and always compare it to server's version just like for mobile apps to check if an update is required? In this case a simple refresh will update the app but I need to know when to refresh the app.

I would greatly appreciate if people with SPA experience can give their feedback on the above points. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a good fit for StackOverflow because it's opinion based. On SO, posts should contain a single question and it should contain code that you have tried but couldn't make work. My feedback, if you need faster response, break your app into separate URLs that load quickly

Answer (score 1):

I have the same situation. For your first concern i use [ocLazyLoad](https://oclazyload.readme.io/).

I load the basic files at the beginning, but only load the files i really need, when the user needed.

With a lazy load, i think i solve the second concern, because ocLazyLoad can reload the file. Setting the cache property to false.

[How to reload resources (HTML/CSS/JS) on version change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32348050/how-to-reload-resources-html-css-js-on-version-change)